# How/where does an asp.net web app asmx codebehind get resolved?

Tags: asp.net, asmx

When creating a new asmx on an asp.net web application project (that compiles into one dll), there is no CodeFile property as it used to on a website project - there is however a CodeBehind="namespace.class" property. Afaik a website project asmx uses CodeFile to hint which dll the codebehind will be compiled into. On a web app asmx I see no hint for this - 
when invoking the asmx codebehind public methods of a web app from javascript, how is the dll where the relevant code lives resolved? Is there some sort of IIS/asp.net in-memory mapping between asmx public methods and the dll they are in?